# jQuery .prependTo() created table causing browser to "lag"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I have a problem I am not able to fix, quite difficult to explain but I will do my best.

Basically I have created a web application (in **CodeIgniter**) that takes some data of an array coming from a **json encoding** and adds rows to a table by using the **jQuery .prependTo()** method in the success function.

Every row of the table contains different elements from the database (coming from the json), depending from the value of the **i** counter.

The code is as the following (i cut the part about the `<tr>` and `<td>` content, it's just styling)

```
$.ajax({
type: "get",
async: false,
....
....
success: function(data) {


                    var i;
                    var item_cost = new Array();
                    var item_name = new Array();
                    var item_code = new Array();
                    var item_interno = new Array();

                    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                       item_cost[i] = data[i].cost;
                       item_name[i] = data[i].name;
                       item_code[i] = data[i].code;
                       item_interno[i] = data[i].codiceinterno;


                       var newTr = // creates the <tr>
                       newTr.html('//creates the <td>')
                       newTr.prependTo("#myTable");
                    }
},
```

I am sorry if it is a bit unclear, if you need me to update the code because I missed something important let me know and I will do it, but this code alone should explain my problem.

The application works beautifully if in the database there are just a little number of rows (for example, i = 300). They are showed and rendered correctly and I don't get any browser slowing process. But when I work with i = 4000 rows, the browser starts acting slow just like the Javascript code is too heavy to render, and i get "lag" while trying to scroll down the html table, or inputting some values in the input boxes inside the table (to later update it by clicking a button). This is my problem: I am quite sure I'm doing something wrong that is loading up too much memory, as I tested this also on very strong computers. Even totally disabling my CSS won't do the trick.

Thanks for any help you can give me, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Well, yes if you do 4000 jQuery instance, 4000 `html()` and 4000 `.prenpendTo` it will be slow...

Comment: So i guess it is normal? Is there a way i can speed up the whole thing? I need my application to be fast and intuitive.

Comment: Let me work on something, i cannot guaranty it will work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem

You are using a lot of function call inside a loop. That take a lot of juice and the more item you have, the slower it is.

To solve that, we need to reduce the number of function calls.

## My suggestion

Working with native JavaScript would save on performance here. So I suggestion you use string concatenation instead of DOM manipulation methods of jQuery.

Let rework you loop. Since you want your data in a descendant order, we need to reverse the loop :

```
for(i = data.length; i >= 0; i--)
```

Then simple string concatenation to build a `tr`. For that you need a var outside the loop:

```
var myHTML = ''; //That's the one!
var i;
var item_cost = new Array();
var item_name = new Array();
var item_code = new Array();
var item_interno = new Array();
```

And build the `tr` with `+=`. Although, using a single line would make it faster, but less readable :

```
for(i = data.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    item_cost[i] = data[i].cost;
    item_name[i] = data[i].name;
    item_code[i] = data[i].code;
    item_interno[i] = data[i].codiceinterno;


    myHTML += '<tr>';
    myHTML += '<td>'+yourData+'</td>';//add those data here
    myHTML += '<td>'+yourData+'</td>';
    myHTML += '<td>'+yourData+'</td>';
    myHTML += '<td>'+yourData+'</td>';
    myHTML += '<td>'+yourData+'</td>';
    myHTML += '</tr>';
}
```

Then, prepend it to your table :

```
var myHTML = '';
var i;
var item_cost = new Array();
var item_name = new Array();
var item_code = new Array();
var item_interno = new Array();

for(i = data.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    item_cost[i] = data[i].cost;
    item_name[i] = data[i].name;
    item_code[i] = data[i].code;
    item_interno[i] = data[i].codiceinterno;


    myHTML += '<tr>';
    myHTML += '<td>'+yourData+'</td>';
    myHTML += '<td>'+yourData+'</td>';
    myHTML += '<td>'+yourData+'</td>';
    myHTML += '<td>'+yourData+'</td>';
    myHTML += '<td>'+yourData+'</td>';
    myHTML += '</tr>';
}

$('#myTable').prepend(myHTML);
```

## Limitation

From my test, the string length can be `2^28` but cannot be `2^29`. That make a maximum length of approx. *268,435,456* (approx. might not be the best word here since it's between *268,435,456* and *536,870,912*.

If you data character count is higher than that (but let be honnest, that would be **a lot** of data), you might have to split you string into 2 variables.

Comment: I will definetly give it a try when I go back at the office, in the while I upvoted this answer. Thanks for now!

Comment: Yeah, using pure javascript is always faster

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a real answer to your question, but...

jQuery definitely causes the lag - no wonder. But - whether you choose jQuery to build the table or you just concatenate HTML - let's agree on that: 4000 rows is definitely a lot of data. Too much data? I would say: 200 already is. If we go thousands, the question pops up: why? Is there any application-related reason you really need to retrieve such a big number of records at once? Some of them will probably never be read.

Why not try an ajax-based lazy load approach? Loading 50-record portions every time would seem more robust IMO, and would definitely be a better UX.

Comment: My application developed ad-hoc for my client requires that. Could you give me an example of this "lazy load" you are saying? Do you mean dividing the results in pages? Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: I don't have any example hanging around, but I generally refer to a mechanism (used on FB or heavy galleries) where a javascript watches user scroll the page to a given threshold. When the threshold is exceeded, ajax loads next portion of data (in your case: table rows). Actually you could set your code so to always have a next screenful of data ready. Lazy load is a popular term for this.

Comment: I will check it but i think that when the client will check all the rows and get to read the 4000+th row, he will lag anyways, won't he?

Comment: You can pre-load 100 rows in advance so to have an overhead of data handy in case client starts scrolling. Then user should not sense the lag. A downside of such infinite scroll is that it's difficult to jump to a given section of data before it's loaded. As I said, it all depends on the UI requirements, but 4000 rows just seems too much to digest at once.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: Why don't retrieve the rows composed from the server instead of making the client work to compound it? You could even cache it. The only thing would be that you'll have more traffic, but in the browser it'll go smoother

### UPDATE

To achieve it, you can make your method to distinguish between `ajax` input or not, and show only `$tbody`, or the whole table according to it. It would be something like:

```
$tbody = $this->load->view( 'view_with_oly_tbody', $data, true );
if ( $this->input->is_ajax_request() ) {
    return $tbody;
} else {
    $data['tbody'] = $tbody;
    $this->load->view('your_view_with_table_with_tbody_as_var', $data);
}
```

Note: Code above will vary according to your views, controller, if you have json in your AJAX or not, write the return in other part, etc. Code above is just for clarify my point with CI.

Ah! and you'll have to manage the answer in the client to append/prepend/substitute the body of the table.

Comment: Have you got any suggestions to achieve what you said? Thanks for the answer!